# Move branch one step back to leave a branchless tagged commit

Tags: git, tags, branch, git-remote, revert

Here is my current situation, working on branch `draft`:

```
* 51c716b (HEAD -> draft, tag: Printed, remote/draft) Dirty squeezing of the draft to be printed on as few pages as possible
* 9219af9 Draft ready for reading
* e3366b2 Making progress on the draft
* 163ab8f (master, remote/master) Create a draft
```

Now that I have got feedback about this `Printed` version of the draft, I wish to
go on with the project. Obviously, the latest commit `51c716b` (tagged as
`Printed`) is not the one I want to resume from: I want to resume from
`9219af9`. But I don't want to loose `51c716b`.

What should I do for the situation to be like this after my next commit?

```
* b57cc00 (HEAD -> draft, remote/draft) Integrate feedback from readers.
| * 51c716b (tag: Printed) Dirty squeezing of the draft to be printed on as few pages as possible
|/
* 9219af9 Draft ready for reading
* e3366b2 Making progress on the draft
* 163ab8f (master, remote/master) Create a draft
```

(I also wish that the tag `Printed` were available on `remote`.)

Note: I am aware that this would cause trouble to people having pulled on `draft` while it was pointing to `51c716b`. But I am confident that nobody has done such a thing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Reset](https://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html). Git branches are references pointing to commits, so you basically want to move the local reference `draft` to point to `9219af9`. You can do so with:

`git reset --hard 9219af9`

Or, if you were to use [ancestry references](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References):

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

After that, you will probably create a new commit (`b57cc00` in your example), and you'll have to update the *remote* reference `draft` (the one that is in `origin`) to point to the new commit. You can do that with:

`git push origin draft --force-with-lease`

[This](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2015/04/force-with-lease/) will tell the remote that you are aware that you are "loosing" `51c716b`. However, Git will still keep commits that have references pointing to it and, since you have a tag (which is also a reference) on `51c716b`, you'll always be able to go back to it. Make sure you push your tag if you want other people (or your future self) to be able to access it:

`git push origin Printed`

Comment: Thanks :) Am I sure that `51c716b` won't actuality be "lost"? Will I still be able to get it back from another machine with `git clone <remote>; git checkout Printed`?

Comment: You will if you push the tag to the remote. I've edited the answer to include  this information.

Comment: Then it is what I was looking for indeed. Thanks! ^ ^